# Has Stack Exchange ever purchased "premium" domain names?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange-history, domain-names

[The landing page of stackoverflow.com in June 2004](https://web.archive.org/web/20040612143406/http://www.stackoverflow.com/) looked something like this:

[image]

Suddenly, [in July of 2008](https://web.archive.org/web/20080710031751/https://stackoverflow.com/) there was a teaser of the site to come:

[image]

The link goes to [the original Stack Overflow blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20080502055220/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/). Jump ahead a bit and there's the Stack Overflow we know and love -- albeit not as sleek then:

[image]

Here's my question: Did Stack Exchange -- or, rather, the folks who became [the founders](https://stackexchange.com/about/management) -- ever buy a "premium" domain? Whether for Stack Overflow, Super User, Ask Ubuntu, or even stackexchange.com itself.

Answer (score 13):

Partial answer: Jeff Atwood spent 10K on superuser.com. [His tweet of May 29, 2009](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1965603283) says:

> seriously considering paying $10k for what I think is a pretty killer domain name. Is this a bad idea? Am I crazy? somebody hold me!

Next day, [Super User was announced](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/). The announcement says "And now that I’ve secured the third domain name..." and gives more details about the acquisition.

> I was thrilled to be able to secure the domain name superuser.com from fellow geek (and dual-class photographer / sysadmin) Noah Beil. As I’ve mentioned before, naming is hard, and it’s so rare to find a name that a) I like, and b) is available. Noah had actually heard of Stack Overflow and even used it a few times to find answers to JavaScript questions; of all the offers for the domain he had gotten over the years, this was the first one he felt was a good fit.